# Есть ли у bootstrap возможность установки тёмного модельного окна?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть такой html код который показывает модальное окно, но оно белого цвета, есть ли возможность сделать его тёмным? Или это нужно делать самому в css?

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="contacts">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i> Контакты </h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Для вопросов касаемых игры - <a class="link" href="#">Текст 1</a></p>
              <p>Для технических вопросов - <span class="contactmail">Текст 2</span></p>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: какая версия бутстрапа?

Comment: @Grundy Версия 4.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы  нет,  только свой CSS.